# Join 1 date string + 1 time string and convert to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

Iam reading from an excel file 2 columns:

One column has value:
07/11/2012

2nd column has value:
18:45

When I read the 2nd column, it shows actually a default date in front of it.
        dr[3].ToString()    "30/12/1899 6:45:00 PM" string

I want to join the first column with the second. but right now I have the normal input format exception

I tried to remove the date part from the second column with string manipulation

here is my code

```
 DateTime dateEvent = DateTime.Parse(dr[1].ToString());
        dateEvent.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(dr[3].ToString().Substring(dr[3].ToString().IndexOf(" ")+1)));
```

**Udpate 1:**

```
DateTime dateEvent = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", dr[1].ToString(), dr[3].ToString().IndexOf(" ") + 1), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Looking at it again, I strongly suspect you don't need to do any parsing at all. I suspect you could use:

```
DateTime date = ((DateTime) dr[1]).Date;
TimeSpan time = ((DateTime) dr[3]).TimeOfDay;
DateTime combined = date + time;
```

You shouldn't just blindly call `ToString()` on values, without understanding what the type is: often it's exactly the right type, and you can save yourself a potentially-lossy string conversion.

---

Assuming you *have* to parse (rather than getting Excel to convert to a `DateTime` for you) I suggest using `DateTime.ParseExact` for both parts:

- For the first part, use a format of `dd/MM/yyyy`
- For the second part, use a format of `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt`

I'd suggest using the invariant culture explicitly - assuming you really know that this format is completely fixed. (If you don't, that's a bigger problem.)

Then join them together like this:

```
DateTime combined = date.Date + time.TimeOfDay;
```

Alternatively, you could use my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library, which has separate `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` concepts, which can be combined easily into a `LocalDateTime`...

Comment: @LuisEValencia: Yes - it looks like you're going through a string conversion for *no reason*. (Editing...)

Comment: first line throws Specified cast is not valid. I have been told that we can assume the format will always be DD-MM-YYYY. dr[3] = "07/11/2012"

Comment: @LuisEValencia: Well have you debugged into it to see what the actual type is? (If it's a string, cast to that instead of calling `ToString`.) I would strongly encourage you to avoid parsing if you *possibly* can. If you do have to parse, see my edited code - now that you've told us the format of the time string, that should work.

Comment: I changed the first line to DateTime date = (DateTime.Parse(dr[1].ToString())).Date;
             and not it works fine

Comment: @LuisEValencia: I'd still try to get to the bottom of why you can't get it as a `DateTime` to start with. The fewer conversions you can get away with, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
string date = dr[1].ToString();
string time = dr[3].ToString();
time = time.Substring(time.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", date, time), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: same exception: look at my code:  DateTime dateEvent = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", dr[1].ToString(), dr[3].ToString().IndexOf(" ") + 1), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Why `dr[3].ToString().IndexOf(" ") + 1)`?? Shouldn't be `dr[3].ToString()`?

Comment: dr[3] is returning a date + a time, even if in the excel file its only a time 18:45

Comment: Ok. Updated my answer to use only the time. You were looking for `Substring`, not `IndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) so you can *specifically* say which parts of the dates you need e.g.

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dr[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", CurrentCulture.InvariantCulture).Date;
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(dr[3], "HH:mm", CurrentCulture.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
var eventDate = date + time;
```